# Sie bezahlen [für?] die Bestellung per PayPal

Tags: sentence-structure, phrase, software

Are all variants absolutely correct and equivalent? If not, what's the difference?

- Sie bezahlen die Bestellung *per PayPal*
- Sie bezahlen **für** die Bestellung *per PayPal*
- Sie bezahlen die Bestellung *mit der Kreditkarte*
- Sie bezahlen **für** die Bestellung *mit der Kreditkarte*

Comment: The definite article in the two latest examples is not required. If previous context did not establish a certain credit card, the sentence appears better without, i. e. *mit Kreditkarte*. This is a classical example of *Nullartikel*, dropping the article if the generic thing is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: yes, they are all correct and equivalent. (Well, paying by PayPal and paying by credit card are not the same thing of course, so they're not *equivalent* in that respect.)

For Paypal, I would personally prefer "per Paypal" to "mit Paypal" in more formal language, because it fits the abstract notion of "sending money using Paypal" better. I would have no problem saying "per Kreditkarte" though, I would probably even slightly prefer that when talking about online payment that doesn't involve using the actual card.

Strangely, the accusative object of "bezahlen" can have two very different meanings:

You can say:

> Ich habe das Essen *(accusative object)* mit meiner Kreditkarte bezahlt.

but also:

> Ich habe fürs Parken einen Euro *(accusative object)* bezahlt.

So the accusative object can either denote what you paid *for*, or it can mean the *amount* you paid. It can not be used for the method of payment though (PayPal, credit card, Überweisung etc.).

So this does not work:

> **incorrect**: Ich habe für das Essen meine Kreditkarte bezahlt.

It's also *not* possible to use both meanings of the accusative object in one sentence, you need to use a preposition for one of them:

> **incorrect**: Ich habe das Essen 10 Euro bezahlt.
> **correct**: Ich habe *für* das Essen 10 Euro bezahlt.
> **correct**: Ich habe das Essen *mit* 10 Euro bezahlt.
> **correct**: Ich habe *für* das Essen *mit* 10 Euro bezahlt.

Comment: One might note that while "Ich habe das Essen mit 10€ bezahlt" is totally correct, it somewhat implies there are or might be alternative payment modes available... like "Ich habe das Essen mit einer Stunde körpernaher Dienstleistungen / Umgraben des gesamten Gartens / meiner Gesundheit / ... bezahlt" ;)

Comment: Thanks @HalvarF for your great explanation. The root cause of the question was that we had been provided with 4 German phrases about 4 different payment methods, and 3 of those phrases didn't contain the für, while specifically the phrase about PayPal did contain it. In terms of software design it makes it a bit more difficult work for a developer, because otherwise we could use the same template for all the cases: "Sie bezahlen die Bestellung ...", but it doesn't work for PayPal, as we need to add the für and therefore have an additional template.

Comment: @JustAndrei: Ah, I see. Yes, you can use the same template ("Sie bezahlen die Bestellung ") for all payment methods.